# I need help converting the following C code to LEGv8 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm64, armv8

For the following C statement, write the corresponding
LEGv8 assembly code. Assume that the variables f, g, h, i, and j are assigned to
registers X0,X1,X2,X3, and X4, respectively. Assume that the base address of the
arrays A and B are in registers X6 and X7, respectively.

```
B[8] = A[i−j];
```

my current approach is as follows

```
SUB X5, X3, X4 
LSL X5, X5, #2
ADD X5, X6, X5 
LDUR ??

ADDI X8, X7, #32
STUR ??
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks like you've correctly calculated load and store addresses.  (Assuming array elements are 32-bit, so you'll be loading / storing into a temporary `w` register, like `w0` or `w5`).  If LEGv8 doesn't have 2-register addressing modes or reg+immediate, then those were both necessary steps.  Actual AArch64 can do scaled-index addressing: https://godbolt.org/z/xjWfoEr8E  and `str     w1, [x0, 32]` is valid for simple small offsets.  So try that first in your LEGv8 assembler to see if it's accepted, or check a quick reference for addressing modes.

Comment: If LEGv8 actually has `stur` as well as `str`, presumably it at least supports an immediate offset from a register.  (That's the thing that would be "scaled" or not in the machine code for `str` vs. `stur`, having to be a multiple of the store width, e.g. 32 is a multiple of 4 in this case so it's encodeable with `str` as well as `stur`.)